# show the txt content in a realtime manner in html( my web server doesn't support php)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a file named log.txt, it is always being written new content by another process ( here is a telnet session by pexpect ), I want to display the whole contents in pages, and when new contents comes in, the page content also show the new contents too, it's a little like tail -f, but a little different, because  I want to show the whole content  besides the new contents just came in

Comment: What commands?  Log of what data?  HTML is markup representing a document, not a program that's ran in a linear way.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and probably worst) way is to download whole each time using ajax request. One of possible implementations using jQuery would be for instance:

```
var logDownloader = {

    fileContents:"",

    init: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "./logfile.txt",
            async: false,
            success: function (data){
                pageExecute.fileContents = data;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Another way would be calling php script which would return only the "fresh" part of text from your log file. For reading file line by line you can use for example:

```
if ($file = fopen("file.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        //send your line
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

You should also send the number of last sent line in order not to send whole file each time.

On the other hand if you're not limited to PHP I would recommend to use nodeJS and socket.io or some python script. In my opinion it would be more efficient.

Comment: Hi Luke, can you post the whole jqurey code here, I know little about jqurey, I don't know how to use it, if I use python scripts, where is my start point? if I use socket.io, do I need to install something to get it work ?

Comment: A good place to start are tutorials and documentations like https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/ I am not going to provide you a full code as stack overflow does not exist for such purposes. We're helping you to get an idea, not a full copy-paste solution.